# TCP client not able to write to socket but receive works fine

Tags: python, sockets

I have client program written in python that talks to some server.

[Client]

```
import asyncore
import logging
import socket
import sys, threading, traceback
from cStringIO import StringIO

class Client(threading.Thread, asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._thread_sockets = dict()
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, map=self._thread_sockets)

        # data members for the module
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.write_buffer = ""
        self.is_connected = False
        self.read_buffer = StringIO()

        # Ok now to run the thread !!
        self.start()

    def run(self) :
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        address = (self.host, self.port)
        self.logger.debug('connecting to %s', address)

        # wait until server is up
        while not self.is_connected :
           try :
              self.connect(address)
           except Exception as ex :
              pass #do nothing, proceed forward !!
        asyncore.loop(map=self._thread_sockets)

    def handle_connect(self):
        self.is_connected = True
        self.logger.debug('handle_connect()')

    def handle_close(self):
        self.logger.debug('handle_close()')
        self.close()

    def handle_error(self):
        traceback.print_exc(sys.stderr)
        self.close()

    def writable(self):
        self.logger.debug('writable() : len is %d bytes', len(self.write_buffer))
        is_writable = (len(self.write_buffer) > 0)
        if is_writable:
            self.logger.debug('writable() -> %s', is_writable)
        return is_writable

    def readable(self):
        self.logger.debug('readable() -> True')
        return True

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.write_buffer)
        self.logger.debug('data len written to socket -> %s', sent)
        self.logger.debug('handle_write() -> "%s"', self.write_buffer[:sent])
        #self.write_buffer = self.write_buffer[sent:]

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        self.logger.debug('handle_read() -> %d bytes', len(data))
        self.read_buffer.write(data)
        self.logger.debug('data received from socket -> %s', self.read_buffer.getvalue())
        self.read_buffer.truncate(0)

    def send(self, data) :
        self.write_buffer = data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(name)s: %(message)s',
                        )
    try :
       client = Client("127.0.0.1", 8182)
       client.send('sending data from client')
    except Exception as ex :
       logging.exception(ex)
       sys.exit(1)
```

I am able to receive data from server correctly but send call to the server always fails. As from the log the send always return 'None'.

Am i missing anything ?

Comment: Why do you consider that a failure case?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : failure because send is not working even though server is running.

Comment: How did you determine the send wasn't working? You see some entry in your log that you haven't shown us that contains "None" in it somewhere. From that, you concluded that the send wasn't working. Can you go through your reasoning?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : LOG : data len written to socket -> None. Return value of send is None indicating 0 bytes were wriiten

Comment: Log the number of bytes you *tried* to send as well. If it's none at all, then there's a bug elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override the `send` method of `asyncore.dispatcher` with code that does not send any data and returns no value:

```
def send(self, data) :
    self.write_buffer = data
```

At the least, you need to change your code to look similar to this:

```
def send_data(self, data):
    self.write_buffer = data
```

and this:

```
client.send_data('sending data from client')
```

The `asyncore.dispatcher` class already has a `send` method which is a wrapper around the `socket.send` method. From `asyncore.py`:

```
def send(self, data):
    try:
        result = self.socket.send(data)
        return result
    except socket.error, why:
        if why.args[0] == EWOULDBLOCK:
            return 0
        elif why.args[0] in _DISCONNECTED:
            self.handle_close()
            return 0
        else:
            raise
```

Because you override this method, your `send` method gets called in your `handle_write` method, and no data is sent to the server.